NVIDIA GPUs on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: one GPU disappears after installing nvidia driver
I have a brand new ubuntu desktop which has two GPUs - A30 and geforce RTX 4080.
NVIDIA SDK was pre-installed, but I could not find nvidia driver.
So I installed the recommended Driver Version: 535.161.08, and restarted the system.
After rebooting, on the main console I cannot see the GUI (reboot.jpg), but I can login from a terminal. I tried updating /etc/default/grub with following
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash loglevel=3 ibt=off”
I also tried running startx from terminal, but it gave error (startx.jpg)
On the terminal, nvidia-smi command after rebooting works fine (see screenshot), but after about 30 minutes gives the following error
$nvidia-smi
Unable to determine the device handle for GPU0000:01:00.0: Unknown Error
$nvidia-smi -L
Unable to determine the device handle for gpu 0000:01:00.0: Unknown Error
GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080 SUPER (UUID: GPU-def59770-4aed-bccf-e063-2c72ab0ac873)
I would like to know how can I

get GUI back on the main console
get both GPUs working

Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Archana
I am including screenshots of above commands and ubuntu-drivers devices command for more information here
screenshots
